# How do Java's proposed Inline Classes compared to Value Types in C#

Tags: java, c#

There is talk once again about [Inline Classes](https://www.infoq.com/articles/inline-classes-java/) being added to Java.

As someone who understands C#, what is the best ways to think about them?

As a C# program what am I likely to misunderstand about them?

Comment: Please provide a reference to what is proposed.

Comment: I assume this is about anonymous interface implementation ([relevant c# request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13)).

Comment: See https://www.infoq.com/articles/inline-classes-java/

Answer (score 4):

Inline classes are C#'s `readonly struct`s (value types). The restrictions are extremely similar (can't inherit from classes, can't be inherited from, can implement interfaces).

Note the `readonly` above. The fields of an inline class are implicitly `final` (`readonly` in C#).

The autoboxing behavior is, according to your linked article, not yet finalized. So we can't currently make any statements on how it differs from .Net's autoboxing and any associated pitfalls. The experimental "indirect projection" feature seems to basically be "explicitly boxed, nullable type variant".

Java does not have C#'s `ref` or `out` parameters, so I would assume that you have to treat all parameters of inline class type the way you treat struct parameters in C#: they're copies. Since they are readonly, the issue of modifications not being visible outside does not appear.

Comment: Another wrinkle is that Java has split-personality type system, where primitives and objects are completely different things with a clear line between, and never the twain shall meet. Inline classes create these weird things that are kinda behaving like one but are actually the other. My personal preference would be to get rid of primitives and re-create them as inline classes, and accepting that this will break code.